# Adding horizontal radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Whenever I try adding radio buttons to my form it becomes vertical and it no longer functions. I need to get the radio to show and be horizontal. I add `input` to each `div` but it alters the forms design and function.

Also I tried:

```
input {
display:inline-block;
}
```

Working JSFiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/RC3e4/16/ (When an option is clicked it displays hidden text)

Non-working JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/RC3e4/23/

```
<div class="" type="radio" name="q1" value="Broken">
```

Comment: display: inline-block?

Comment: But... this markup doesn't create a radio button!

Comment: The width and padding on your `div type=radio` are forcing the second and third elements on a new line.  Also, shouldn't you be using `input` in your html as radio buttons instead of `div`?

Comment: Type isn't a valid attribute for div.

Comment: @EnjoysTurtles `inline-block doesn't work either

Comment: Please update your JSFiddle so that each `<div type="">` is changed to an `<input type="">`. As mentioned already, `type` isn't a valid attribute for `<div>s`.

Comment: @steinmas update: http://jsfiddle.net/RC3e4/5/ | still doesn't work

Comment: Don't forget to remove extra <divs>. I would suggest stripping out all the javascript and unnecessary CSS from the JSFiddle until you have the radio button choices working properly in CSS. Then add everything else.

Comment: You have `<br>` tags in your html, this html tag forces a new line.  Remove these tags.

Comment: Read the other comments, I only addressed CSS term

Comment: @TylerH update: http://jsfiddle.net/RC3e4/15/ | doesn't work and will do

Comment: This HTML is really bad. Really out dated, not semantic or accessible. Getting those things figured out first will make what you are trying to do a lot easier.

Comment: @MatthewDarnell http://jsfiddle.net/RC3e4/16/ | Problem fixed

Comment: @EnjoysTurtles http://jsfiddle.net/RC3e4/16/ | Problem fixed

Comment: Accept the answer from hamobi

Comment: @EnjoysTurtles Please check now. I applied hamobi's markup but my script no longer funtions.

Comment: you need to start this from the ground up.  make your html valid.  learn which attributes belong to certain elements.  work on this step by step.  it's hard to help because youre taking my answer and dropping it into a bunch of bad markup..  that wont work well

Answer (score 4):

first of all.  divs don't have a `type` attribute.  Theres no reason to use that.  You can give them an `id`, or a `class` to identify them.

second of all.  divs are block elements.  this means they go top to bottom.  html has no way of knowing whether you want things to flow from left to right, or top to bottom.  You need to use the `float` css property on the divs.

when things become difficult.  you need to make a basic example and work from there.

here is a simple example to work from

http://jsfiddle.net/pPcHt/

Comment: Spent some time stripping the HTML but I removed everything and followed your steps but what happens is that the code no longer function when I updated it. Check my post for updated fiddles.